# Maptiler Pro Demo 12 Core using only 12%

Tags: google-maps-api-3, maptiler

Using MapTiler Pro Demo. Testing zoom levels 1-21 for Google Maps export from a tiff image (about 21mb file covering polygons over 2000km).

At the moment its been running an hour with constant usage at 12% of 12 vcores (about 1.5 of 12) maxed to about 2.5ghz. No tiles has been exported yet, only the html's associated.

Am I too quick to judge performance?

Edit: Progressbar at 0%

Edit2: Hour 8 still 0%. Memory usage increased from 400mb to 2gb

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to generate from your input 21 MBytes file about 350 GBytes of tiles (approx. 10 billion of map tiles at zoom level 21) by the options you have set in the software. Is this really what you want to do?

It sounds like a nonsense to render the very low-res image (2600 x 2000 pixel) covering a large area (such as the South Africa) down to zoom level 21!

The software has suggested you the default maxzoom 6. If your data are coverage maps or similar dataset it makes sense to render it maybe down to zoom level 12 or similar, definitely not deeper than 14. For standard input data (aerial photo) the native suggested maxzoom +1 or +2 is the max which really makes sense. Deeper zoom levels do not add any visual advantage.

The user can always zoom deeper - but the upper tiles can be displayed on the client side - so you don't really need to generate and save all these images at all...

MapTiler automatically provides you with a Google Maps V3 viewer, which is doing the client-side over zooming out of the box.

See a preview here:
http://tileserver.maptiler.com/#weather/gmapsmaptiler.embed

If you are interested in the math behind the map tiles, check:
http://tools.geofabrik.de/calc/#type=geofabrik_standard&bbox=16.44,-34.85,32.82,-22.16

Thanks for providing the report (with http://www.maptiler.com/how-to/submit-report/) to us. Your original email to our support did not contain any technical data at all (not even the data you write here on the stackoverflow).

Please, before you publicly rant on the performance of a software - double check you know what you do. MapTiler Pro is a powerful tool, but the user must know what he does.

Based on your feedback - we have decided to implement for a future version of the MapTiler software an estimated final output size - and warn the user in the graphical user interface if he chooses options which are probably unwanted.

Comment: Thanks for the opportunity to try your demo. I think I will continue using Global Mapper

Comment: Your dataset can be easily rendered with MapTiler Start or Plus - you don't even need Pro. Try the speed of rendering to the same zoom level range and compare the produced size of the tiles with alternative software tools - and decide...

Comment: I noticed the tiling isn't as resource hungry as I thought, which is great. Maybe i'll try with some decent data and compare the two. My estimate at the moment is advantage towards maptiler